# AWS Lambda Connect to Redshift DB using ODBC Connection

Tags: c#, lambda, odbc, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect to RedShift DB Using AWS Lambda from .NEt Core 2.0 C# App.

Below is my approach.

```
string connString = "Driver={Amazon Redshift (x86)};" +
            String.Format("Server={0};Database={1};" +
            "UID={2};PWD={3};Port={4};SSL=true;Sslmode=Require",
            RedShiftServer, RedShiftDBName, RedShiftUsername,RedShiftPassword, RedShiftPort);
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
```

But I am not able to connect to RedShift DB (Unable to Open the connection) after deployment to Lambda Function.

I am getting Bellow Error.

> "Dependency unixODBC with minimum version 2.3.1 is required.
>       Unable to load DLL 'libodbc.so.2': The specified module or one of its 
>       dependencies could not be found.

It seems some odbc issue, how to solve it ?

Comment: I got a way around using this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947828/aws-redshift-net-core-odbc-support

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying ODBC for getting data from redshift for my lambda function but was getting issue "Dependency unixODBC with minimum version 2.3.1 is required".

Instead of using ODBC use **Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL** library as mentioned in comments in this thread. I am trying to put it together to help. Here is my code which reads the connection string of odbc from redshift and bind it with your model whose type and column name of table in redshift should be same irrespective of casing.

```
 public IEnumerable<T> ExcecuteSelectCommand<T>(string command, string connectionString)
    {
        var relevantConnectionString = GetConnectionStringWithoutDriver(connectionString);
        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(relevantConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = command;
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    return CreateList<T>(reader);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("There was exception while excecuting the Select Command for Detail, here is exception detail. " + ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetConnectionStringWithoutDriver(string connection)
    {
        return connection.Replace("Driver={Amazon Redshift (x64)}; ", string.Empty);
    }


    private List<T> CreateList<T>(NpgsqlDataReader reader)
    {
        var results = new List<T>();
        Func<NpgsqlDataReader, T> readRow = this.GetReader<T>(reader);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                var readData = readRow(reader);
                results.Add(readData);

            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Data mismatch exception has occured");
                //Log the information when data failed to load
            }

        }

        return results;
    }

    private Func<NpgsqlDataReader, T> GetReader<T>(NpgsqlDataReader reader)
    {
        Delegate resDelegate;

        List<string> readerColumns = new List<string>();
        for (int index = 0; index < reader.FieldCount; index++)
        {
            readerColumns.Add(reader.GetName(index));
        }

        // determine the information about the reader
        var readerParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(NpgsqlDataReader), "reader");
        var readerGetValue = typeof(NpgsqlDataReader).GetMethod("GetValue");

        // create a Constant expression of DBNull.Value to compare values to in reader
        var dbNullValue = typeof(System.DBNull).GetField("Value");
        //var dbNullExp = Expression.Field(Expression.Parameter(typeof(System.DBNull), "System.DBNull"), dbNullValue);
        var dbNullExp = Expression.Field(expression: null, type: typeof(DBNull), fieldName: "Value");
        // loop through the properties and create MemberBinding expressions for each property
        List<MemberBinding> memberBindings = new List<MemberBinding>();
        foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            // determine the default value of the property
            object defaultValue = null;
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
                defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
            else if (prop.PropertyType.Name.ToLower().Equals("string"))
                defaultValue = string.Empty;

            if (readerColumns.Contains(prop.Name.ToLower()))
            {
                // build the Call expression to retrieve the data value from the reader
                var indexExpression = Expression.Constant(reader.GetOrdinal(prop.Name.ToLower()));
                var getValueExp = Expression.Call(readerParam, readerGetValue, new Expression[] { indexExpression });

                // create the conditional expression to make sure the reader value != DBNull.Value
                var testExp = Expression.NotEqual(dbNullExp, getValueExp);
                var ifTrue = Expression.Convert(getValueExp, prop.PropertyType);
                var ifFalse = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(defaultValue), prop.PropertyType);

                // create the actual Bind expression to bind the value from the reader to the property value
                MemberInfo mi = typeof(T).GetMember(prop.Name)[0];
                MemberBinding mb = Expression.Bind(mi, Expression.Condition(testExp, ifTrue, ifFalse));
                memberBindings.Add(mb);
            }
        }

        // create a MemberInit expression for the item with the member bindings
        var newItem = Expression.New(typeof(T));
        var memberInit = Expression.MemberInit(newItem, memberBindings);


        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<NpgsqlDataReader, T>>(memberInit, new ParameterExpression[] { readerParam });
        resDelegate = lambda.Compile();

        return (Func<NpgsqlDataReader, T>)resDelegate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use System.Data.Odbc on non-Windows platform you have to install unixODBC (version 2.3.1 or higher). Then, you need to install ODBC driver you need (in your case this is Amazon Redshift ODBC driver) and register it in odbcinst.ini. In case of AWS Lambda you need to check how to deploy unixODBC and Redshift ODBC driver with your deployment package.

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, I am also facing this issue could you help me with it in more detail. As i am very new to this.

Comment: @shekharsingh if you need to connect to Redshift from .NET it might be easier to use managed NpgSql driver instead of ODBC

Comment: Thank you @Vitaliy That helped.